# Can not get python script running in R (Error in sys$stdout$flush() : attempt to apply non-function)

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm trying to call a python script in R using `library(reticulate)`, however I get the following error:

> sys$stdout$flush() : attempt to apply non-function

I have python3 in my windows computer which is installed, using anaconda. I cannot run even a simple hello world...

```
library(reticulate)
source_python('hello-world.py')
```

> sys$stdout$flush() : attempt to apply non-function

I also tried to set the python path like this:

```
use_python("C:/Users/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3")
```

and still not working.